# Why is the Ruby Time Zone Designator formatting in strftime not working?

Tags: ruby, strftime, xml-sitemap

I am building [a sitemap for Google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/183668?hl=en&ref_topic=6080646&rd=1), and want to use Ruby to format the datetime in their recommended format using the W3C standard with the time zone, like this,

```
YYYY-MM-DDThh:mmTZD
```

where TZD is the Time Zone Designator. However the default format being exported from the last_updated field from an SQL database by Ruby on Rails has spaces in it, eg

```
2014-09-19 10:33:05 UTC
```

How do I format the datetime in ruby to remove spaces and include the time zone in the correct format?

TZD can be accessed in ruby using the strftime method, like this:

```
myobject.updated_at.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")
```

This will format time with TZD in the following format

```
2014-09-26T07:53:14+0000
```

However I need to get the TZD in format +00:00

According to [the Ruby docs](http://apidock.com/ruby/Time/strftime) I should be able to use

```
%:z
```

However this shows up as

```
2014-09-26T08:10:21%:z
```

ruby 1.8.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but the docs you are linking are for latest stable version (1.9.3), not 1.8.7 - which BTW - is no longer supported. And it seems that `%:z` option was not available in Ruby 1.8.7.

There are also stable versions: 2.0.0, and 2.1.3 - in any of them you will get required behaviour.